# Error while casting java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList to com.google.protobuf.Message

Tags: java, json, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java

I am getting a response from a gRPC call in the form of Dynamic Message, which has nested fields.
For that, I am trying to get the first level field first, and then using this object to fetch the nested fields, this is how the response looks:

```
field1 {
  key1: "value1"
}
field2 {
  key1: "value1"
  key2: value2
  key3 {
    netsed_key_1: "nested_val_1"
    netsed_key_2: "nested_val_2"
  }
  key4 {
    netsed_key_1: "nested_val_1"
    netsed_key_2: "nested_val_2"
  }
}
```

So, what happens is when I fetch based on field2, I get this:

```
key1: "value1"
  key2: value2
  key3 {
    netsed_key_1: "nested_val_1"
    netsed_key_2: "nested_val_2"
  }
  key4 {
    netsed_key_1: "nested_val_1"
    netsed_key_2: "nested_val_2"
  }
```

The response belongs to the Object class.
But, now to get the nested fields, I need to typecast it to Message, as I will be using the library method:

```
FieldDescriptor fieldDescriptor = message.getDescriptorForType().findFieldByName("nested_key_1");
```

But when I try to cast the Object to the Message class, I get this error:
description=Failed to read message., cause=java.lang.ClassCastException: `java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList cannot be cast to com.google.protobuf.Message`

Is there any other way to do this typecasting ?

```
Object subMessage =
                message.getField(message.getDescriptorForType().findFieldByName("field2"));
 Message sub = (Message) subMessage;
 Object subSubMessage =
             sub.getField(sub.getDescriptorForType().findFieldByName("nested_key_1"));
            System.out.println(subMessage + " " + subSubMessage);
```

Here I get the casting exception.

Comment: It will be good if you include the actual proto definition in the proto syntax instead of the "JSONy" style. Also the castException from `UnmodifiableRandomAccessList` indicates this might have been a repeating field so how about using `getRepeatedField` (with index) instead of `getField` ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `field2` is a repeated field. Cast it to `java.util.List` and access individual objects through the collection.